# How to create MinMaxPriorityQueue with nested generic parameters?

Tags: java, generics, guava

How do I create a `MinMaxPriorityQueue` with nested generic parameters like:

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<AtomicCountHolder<E>> sortedHeap;
```

I've tried all kinds of variations I could think of with the static `create()` method, and the Builder to no avail. It works with

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Integer> s = MinMaxPriorityQueue. <Integer>create();
```

But not with nested generics. Any clues would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

`MinMaxPriorityQueue.create()` imposes a restriction that the generic type must implement the `Comparable` interface, i.e. there is a natural ordering of instances of that type.

I assume `AtomicCountHolder<E>` does not implement `Comparable`. In this case you must provide a custom `Comparator` which defines an ordering of your types. For example,

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<AtomicCountHolder<E>> sortedHeap = MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(someFunction)).create();
```

This assumes you have a `Function` that takes `AtomicCountHolder<E>` and returns something that is `Comparable`, like an `Integer`. Assuming `E` is comparable, you could write a `Function` that takes a `AtomicCountHolder<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` and returns whatever the `AtomicCountHolder` refers to.

What is `AtomicCountHolder` btw? Is it like `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: AtomicCountHolder<E> extends AtomicInteger

So it should implement Comparable.

Comment: @Hein: `AtomicInteger` isn't `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: @sjr's answer is right, then — your `AtomicCountHolder<E>` class needs to implement `Comparable<AtomicCountHolder<E>>`. [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) doesn't implement `Comparable<AtomicInteger>`, by the way.

---

In addition, `E` needs to be a declared type. You either need to define the priority queue in a class with a parameter type named `E`:

```
public class Example<E> {
  MinMaxPriorityQueue<AtomicCountHolder<E>> sortedHeap =
      MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();
}
```

... or you need to specify an existing type in its place:

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<AtomicCountHolder<Integer>> sortedHeap =
    MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();
```

You can also use wildcards as you normally would elsewhere (assuming there are no constraints on the parameter type of `AtomicCountHolder`):

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<AtomicCountHolder<?>> sortedHeap =
    MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();
```

Comment: This first caes you sketch is exactly what I have with the parameter type E declared in the top level class like Example<E>, but your MinMaxPriorityQueue.create() approach does not work. It gives the following: Bound mismatch: The generic method create() of type MinMaxPriorityQueue<E> is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type Example.AtomicCountHolder<E> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>>.

Comment: See my edit — basically `AtomicCountHolder` needs to be Comparable and it isn't as @sjr points out.

Comment: Ups! Thanks. This looks like its going to solve my issue. Thanks! I'll report back with a more concrete example for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Note that MinMaxPriorityQueue assumes that its elements do not change in a way that alters their ordering. If the AtomicCountHolder class is mutable, as its name suggests, you could have incorrect behavior.